# Overloaded Constructor calling other constructors based on input type

Tags: java, constructor

Say I have two constructors taking some type of input. (T1 and T2 in this example)

I want to call either of them from a more general constructor taking an Object (or any superclass of T1 and T2 for that matter)

```
class Test{
    public Test(T1 input){...}
    public Test(T2 input){...}

    public Test(Object input){
        if(input instanceof T1)
            this((T1) input);
        if(input instanceof T2)
            this((T2) input);
}
```

The third constructor would give a compile error since the `this` constructor call isn't on the first line.

Comment: It is not possible in Java. You should fulfill your requirement in another way. If you need more help you should add your specific requirement.

Comment: Why you do not cast before creating the test object?

Comment: @Vasei if the T1 or T2 are being returned by some other method in the form of an Object (In my case, a deserializer which can either return a Map or a String) then the class handling the deserialization could just pass that down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a kind of factory method as follows:

```
public class Test {
    private Test(T1 input) {
        // ...
    }

    private Test(T2 input) {
        // ...
    }

    public static Test createTest(Object input) {
       if (input instanceof T1)
          return new Test((T1) input);
       if (input instanceof T2)
          return new Test((T2) input);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the only way then I'll use it, but it just seems a bit strange to create an object of a class using a static method from that class instead of a constructor

Comment: I don't think that this is the only method. But it is also not a strange way of creating objects. You might want to read [Item 1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151) in the book Effective Java why it is better option than using constructor

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writting three constructors, just write one constructor (the one with Object parameter) and transform the two others into private methods. Now call it like this:

```
class Test{
    private void initT1(T1 input){...}
    private void initT2(T2 input){...}

    public Test(Object input){
        if(input instanceof T1)
            initT1((T1) input);
        else if(input instanceof T2)
            initT2((T2) input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered this, but this solution wouldn't work if the class contained final fields

Answer (score 0):

instanceof is necessary? when T1 is superclass of T2.

```
class T1 { }
class T2 extends T1 { }

class Test {
  public Test(T1 input) { ... }
  public Test(T2 input) {
    this((T1)input); // T2 extends T1.
    // or
    if(input instanceof T1) { this((T1)input); }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Not valid. T2 doesn't extend T1. Also, this would produce the same error.

Comment: Okay, I miss-understood your question. sorry. :( however I recommend factory method as ujulu shows.